# Can I stack two graphs on top of each other? One is stacked bar graph, the other is a line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am trying to show stacked bar graph (x=year, y=population_count(different cut-off of calcium)) and line plot (x=year, y=calcium) simultaneously. Something like the attachment. I tried to create the stacked bar graph first, and add geom_line. But it kept showing the aesthestics issue.Then I tried to create the two graphs separately, but had trouble overlapping them. I have attached my code below, which is the step I took to create two graphs

[image]
[image]

```
# Categorize calcium intake into intervals
data$calc_category <- cut(data$calc, 
                       breaks = c(0, 1000, 1200, 2000, Inf),
                       labels = c("<EAR", ">=EAR,<RDA", ">=RDA,<UL", ">=UL"),
                       include.lowest = TRUE)

# Calculate the proportion of population in each interval for each survey year
prop_data <- data %>%
  group_by(SDDSRVYR, calc_category) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(SDDSRVYR) %>%
  mutate(prop_count = count / sum(count))

prop_data$calc_category <- factor(prop_data$calc_category, 
                                  levels = c(">=UL", ">=RDA,<UL", ">=EAR,<RDA", "<EAR"))

#rename survey year
prop_data$SDDSRVYR <- factor(prop_data$SDDSRVYR, 
                             levels = unique(prop_data$SDDSRVYR),
                             labels = c("2007-2008", "2009-2010", "2011-2012", "2013-2014", "2015-2016", "2017-2018"))


# Create the stacked bar graph
ggplot(prop_data, aes(x = SDDSRVYR, y = prop_count, fill = calc_category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.5) +
  labs(title = "Proportion of Population by Calcium Intake Interval and Survey Year",
       x = "Survey Cycle (Year)",
       y = "Proportion of Population") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", name = "Calcium Intake") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
         legend.box = "horizontal")

### line plot #####

# calculate survey mean of calcium_total
# Define the survey design
survey_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, weights = ~WTDRD1, data = data)

# Calculate the weighted mean of calc for each SDDSRVYR
mean_calc <- svyby(~calc, ~SDDSRVYR, design = survey_design, FUN = svymean)

# Print the mean_calc dataframe
print(mean_calc)

#rename survey year variable level
mean_calc$SDDSRVYR <- factor(mean_calc$SDDSRVYR, 
                             levels = unique(mean_calc$SDDSRVYR),
                             labels = c("2007-2008", "2009-2010", "2011-2012", "2013-2014", "2015-2016", "2017-2018"))

#line plot of mean calcium intake
ggplot(mean_calc, aes(x = SDDSRVYR, y = calc)) +
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(color = "black", aes(group = 1), size = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = calc - se, ymax = calc + se), width = 0.06) +
  labs(title = "Mean Calcium Intake by Survey Year",
       x = "Survey Cycle (Year)",
       y = "Mean Dietary Calcium Intake (mg/d)") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2000), position = "right") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: You'll want to use [`sec_axis`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) for this, which involves creating a common y variable across both datasets and joining them together to plot. I can't show you how to do this on your data though. If you were able to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by sharing or simulating data to produce example graphs that would help get a working answer.